# custom buttons for taking picture in camerawesome flutter

Tags: flutter, camera

I am using camerawesome plugin for flutter
I want to add my own custom button to take picture not the default.
I am able to hide all the controls now I need to know how to take picture from a button Tab or Pressed

following is my code

```
          SizedBox(
            width: screenWidth,
            height: screenHeight,
            child: CameraAwesomeBuilder.custom(
              builder: (cameraState, previewSize, previewRect) {
                return cameraState.when(
                    onPreparingCamera: (state) =>
                        const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                    onPhotoMode: (state) => TakePhotoUI(state));
                //onPhotoMode: (photoCameraState) => photoCameraState.takePhoto());
              },
              saveConfig: SaveConfig.photo(
                pathBuilder: () => path(CaptureMode.photo),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the state on Photo Mode in variable and use it in your custom button

Comment: Can you add any code to help the OP implement the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use bottomActionsBuilder to build your own UI.

```
    bottomActionsBuilder: (state) {
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  AwesomeOrientedWidget(
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 45,
                        width: 45,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                        ),
                        child: Container(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 5),
                        child: _getCaptureButton(state),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: AwesomeFlashButton(state: state),
                  )
                ],
              );
            }


Widget? _getCaptureButton(CameraState state) {
    return state.when(
      onPhotoMode: (state) => _getFloatingActionButton(
        state,
        CaptureMode.photo,
        false,
      ),
      onVideoMode: (state) => _getFloatingActionButton(
        state,
        CaptureMode.video,
        false,
      ),
      onVideoRecordingMode: (state) => _getFloatingActionButton(
        state,
        CaptureMode.video,
        true,
      ),
    ) as Widget?;
  }

Widget _getFloatingActionButton(
    CameraState state,
    CaptureMode captureMode,
    bool isRecording,
  ) {
    final fab = FloatingActionButton(
      heroTag: 'camera_click',
      shape: const CircleBorder(),
      onPressed: () => _handleOnPress(state, captureMode, isRecording),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FittedBox(
            fit: captureMode == CaptureMode.video && !isRecording
                ? BoxFit.none
                : BoxFit.fill,
            child: captureMode == CaptureMode.photo
                ? const Icon(
                    Icons.lens,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )
                : isRecording
                    ? Icon(Icons.stop, color: Colors.red[900])
                    : Icon(Icons.lens, color: Colors.red[900]),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

So far camerawesome is the best camera package but the documentation is incomplete. here's my way

```
onPhotoMode: (state) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32.0),
                          child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              state.takePhoto().then((value) {
                                print(value);
                              });
                            },
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            shape: const CircleBorder(),
                            child: const Icon(
                              Icons.camera_alt,
                              size: 24,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
```

value contains the photo path